# Не работает метод parseInt. JAVA

Tags: java

При работе  с ДЗ, хотел но не реализовал одну функцию, а именно: в 32-й строке (скриншот 1)  сделал переменную со сканером строки - String, а на 33-й строке переменную  int с методом parseInt .
Для того, чтобы на этапе выбора  если пользователь введет неверное число (которого нету в аргументах case, оператора  Switch) или же  текст,  то выдавалось бы на консоль сообщение ("Некорректный ввод").

У меня ругается на 32-ю строку.
Поэтому  был вынужден сделать ввод информации как на (скриншоте 2) - сканером числа nextInt()

Сам код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
     static void calcFract(double a, double b) {
    if (Math.abs(a - b) < 0.0000001) {
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Результат: Числа равны.");
        } else {
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Результат: Числа неравны.");
        }   }
     static void outName() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Какую операцию Вы хотите выполнить?");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("1 - Сравнить");
    System.out.println("2 - Округлить");
    System.out.println("3 - Отбросить дробную часть");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Введите номер операции:");   }
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите число:");
    double num1 = scanner.nextDouble();
    Thread.sleep(300);
    outName();
    **String aname1 = scanner.nextLine();**
    int name1 = Integer.parseInt(aname1);
    System.out.println();
    switch (name1) {
      case 1:
        System.out.println("Введите число с которым хотите провести сравнение:");
        double num2 = scanner.nextDouble();
        calcFract(num1,num2);
        break;
        case 2:
          Thread.sleep(300);
          System.out.println("Результат округления равен = " + Math.round(num1));
          break;
          case 3:
            Thread.sleep(300);
            long x = (long) num1;
            System.out.println("Результат равен = " + x);
            break;
            default:
            System.out.println("Неккоретный ввод, повторите попытку.");
    }    }   }
```

Comment: нет скриншотов, пометьте код комментариями

Answer (score 1):

Так попробуйте

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AreaCounter {

  static void calcFract(double a, double b) {
    if (Math.abs(a - b) < 0.0000001) {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Результат: Числа равны.");
    } else {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Результат: Числа неравны.");
    }
  }

  static void outName() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Какую операцию Вы хотите выполнить?");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("1 - Сравнить");
    System.out.println("2 - Округлить");
    System.out.println("3 - Отбросить дробную часть");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Введите номер операции:");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите число:");
    double num1 = scanner.nextDouble();
    Thread.sleep(300);
    outName();
    scanner.nextLine();
    String aname1 = scanner.nextLine();
    int name1 = Integer.parseInt(aname1);
    System.out.println();
    switch (name1) {
      case 1:
        System.out.println("Введите число с которым хотите провести сравнение:");
        double num2 = scanner.nextDouble();
        calcFract(num1, num2);
        break;
      case 2:
        Thread.sleep(300);
        System.out.println("Результат округления равен = " + Math.round(num1));
        break;
      case 3:
        Thread.sleep(300);
        long x = (long) num1;
        System.out.println("Результат равен = " + x);
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("Неккоретный ввод, повторите попытку.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Скомпилилась, а из-за чего компиляция не проходила?

Comment: думаю из-за  **.

Comment: Если ответ помог то галочка под стрелками